# No elevated permissions when using GUI applications on i3 wm

Tags: permissions, lubuntu, i3

I'm running Lubuntu 13.10 with the i3 window manager. Tasks that need elevated permissions, like installing applications from the lubuntu software center or using the gnome-disks, complain about not having sufficient permissions and never prompt for a password.  Sudo through the command line works so it seems to be just an issue with GUI applications.  Everything works as normal when running vanilla lubuntu.

Comment: Are you all the way up to date?

Comment: @Seth Updated everything I could through apt-get and software updater.

Comment: Might it be an issue with polkit? (which handles "elevating" permissions)

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of no polikit program to ask you for the password. I use lxpolkit for this, here is part of my `.xinitrc`

```
... some other things to run
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxpolkit &
exec dbus-launch i3
```